# NPM Package Manager on Android?

Tags: android, node.js, npm

So I need a module. Using the old trick of (https://registry.npmjs.org/) I can download a single module, but that module has a dependency module which can have more on them. Its tedious. I can't use Termux (I have android 6) Is there any way to install npm package manager on android? I already have NodeJS Front End for Android, but I can't do new things without new modules. Any console with npm would work... Or an script to download npm modules and dependency's on node would work too...

Comment: <dude-what.gif>?! What are you talking about? Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-8.5.0.tgz
- Untar *npm-8.5.0.tgz* to a local directory, e.g. */storage/emulated/0/*
- Move to *npm-8.5.0* and create directory *cache*
- Now open [NodeJS Frontend](https://github.com/warren-bank/Android-NodeJS-Frontend)
- Press +, set title and browse to an empty directory *the-package-dir* except for a *node_modules* subdirectory.
- Set environment variable:
  npm_config_cache=/storage/emulated/0/npm-8.5.0/cache
- Path to js file:
  /storage/emulated/0/npm-8.5.0/package/bin/npm-cli.js
- js file cli options:
  install --omit=dev --omit=optional --omit=peer --no-bin-links --ignore-scripts --no-audit --no-fund the-package
- save and run

Now **the-package** installed in directory *the-package-dir*

Comment: Impressive, it actually worked. Thank you!